# Homomorphism from $\mathbb Z/45\mathbb Z\to \mathfrak S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can I find the homomorphism $\mathbb Z/45\mathbb Z\to \mathfrak S_4$ and the homomorphism $\mathfrak S_4\to\mathbb Z/45\mathbb Z $ ?

I have absolutely no idea how to process.

Comment: A hint for part one: We have $x^{12}=1$ for all $x\in S_4$. Therefore all multiples of $12$ in $\Bbb{Z}/45\Bbb{Z}$ need to go to the neutral element. A hint for part two:  $\Bbb{Z}/45\Bbb{Z}$ is abelian so all commutators need to map to the neutral element.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb Z_{45}\to S_4$. Remark that $\mathbb Z_{45}=<1>$ and thus $f$ is totally determinate by $f(1)$.

You know that the indice of $\ker f$ divide 45. Moreover, by the first theorem of isomorphism, $$\mathbb Z_{45}/\ker f$$ is isomorphe to a subgroup of $S_4$ and thus $[\mathbb Z_{45}:\ker f]$ divide $24$. Since $\gcd(45,24)=3$, $f$ is the identity or is such that $f(k)=\sigma ^k$ where $k$ is a $3$ cycle.

To be honest, for $g:S_4\to\mathbb Z_{45}$ I don't really know, but we can remark that every transposition are in $\ker g$ since the order of a transposition is $2$ and $2$ not divide 45. I don't know if it help.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see why the fact that $[\mathbb Z_{45}:\ker f]$ divide 24 ans the fact that the order of $\ker f$ divide 45 imply that $\ker f$ is of order $3$ and $f(k)=\sigma ^k$ for a 3 cycle.

Comment: As every transposition is in $\ker g$, it follows that $g$ is trivial.